# Why this convenience init doesn't introduce ambiguity in Swift?

Tags: swift

```
@objc public convenience init(size: CGSize, name: String? = nil, address: Address? = nil, order: [Item] = [], phone: String? = nil) {
    self.init(size: size, name: name, address: address, order: order)
    self.phone = phone
}

@objc public required init(size: CGSize, name: String? = nil, address: Address? = nil, order: [Item] = []) {}
```

The convenience initializer is calling the required initializer in the code above. In my test, I try to call

```
let object = ClassA(size: .zero)
```

I was hoping to see the compiler complaining about ambiguity, because both initializers can be called in such a way. However, it actually compiles, and call the `required` initializer. But why? Why there's no ambiguity in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function that doesn't take an argument is considered a better match than a function with an argument with a default value. Compare:

```
func f(_ arg: String = "") { print("unary") }
func f() { print("nullary") }
f()
```

Output:

```
nullary
```

It is ambiguous if both functions have arguments with default values:

```
func f(_ arg: String = "") { print("string") }
func f(_ arg: Int = 1) { print("int") }
f()
```

Output:

```
error: Untitled Page 2.xcplaygroundpage:4:1: error: ambiguous use of 'f'
f()
^

Untitled Page 2.xcplaygroundpage:2:6: note: found this candidate
func f(_ arg: String = "") { print("string") }
     ^

Untitled Page 2.xcplaygroundpage:3:6: note: found this candidate
func f(_ arg: Int = 1) { print("int") }
     ^
```

Comment: Fascinating. Is that nullary preference over unary with default values actually documented anywhere? Or is this behavior undefined and, as such, not to be relied upon. And even if the compiler guarantees this behavior, it seems that this would best be avoided, regardless, as it makes it harder for us poor humans to reason about the code.

Comment: It is discussed in [TypeChecker.rst](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/9f591c9f1f6bf5a479507340601c53c14dbbc420/docs/TypeChecker.rst#comparing-solutions) but not, I think, fully specified. Note, however, that the algorithm can't be changed without breaking source compatibility.